# Reusable Scala code for all views in Play

Tags: templates, playframework, playframework-2.0, reusability

I know I can declare a reusable pure Scala block like this in a template:

```
@title(text: String) = @{
  text.split(' ').map(_.capitalize).mkString(" ")
}
```

I can now call `@title("someString")` in the template but this code block is not accessible from outside this template.

How can I declare such a block that is accessible from other templates as well?

I've tried to create a new template **title.scala.html** like this:

```
@(text : String)
@{
    text.split(' ').map(_.capitalize).mkString(" ")
}
```

I can now call `@title("someString")` from any template I want, but this doesn't give me the exact same result as the first block, inside the template (I assume in the first case it returns a `String` whereas it returns `Html` in the second case).

I'm using Play framework 2.0.4 and I'm coding in Java (hence my limited Scala knowledge).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `tags` is targeted for building reusable blocks of HTML code, therefore it returns `Html`

To work easily with common types of data you can easily add a custom Java class (for an example in freshly created `utils` package (in `app` directory), and prepare in it all required formatters as a static methods:

`utils.MyFormats.java:`

```
package utils;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.text.WordUtils;

public class MyFormats {

    public static String capitalize(String str) {
        return WordUtils.capitalize(str);
    }

    public static int sumElements(int a, int b) {
        return a + b;
    }

}
```

In template:

```
<h2>Capitalized each word: @(utils.MyFormats.capitalize("foo bar"))</h2>
<h3>Sum of two integers, 2+3 = @(utils.MyFormats.sumElements(2, 3))</h3>
```